# How to edit URL based on user input using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, input, user-input

I have below demo`URL`, as you can see I am searching for terms/string "US" and "China" with start date 2021-01-01 and  end date 2021-01-31.The search terms can be 2 or more than 2 or just 1 and also start and end date will vary based on user input. I was wondering if there is a way where I can edit URL based on user input including start and enddate ? Below is code I have so far

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts!

**DEMO URL**

```
URL= "https://covid.org/data?terms=US&terms=CHN&start=2021-01-01T00:00:00Z&end=2021-01-31T00:00:00Z"
```

**Code:**

```
a,b = input("Enter terms:").split()
URL="https://covid.org/data?terms={}&terms={}&start=2021-01-01T00:00:00Z&end=2021-01-31T00:00:00Z".format(a,b)
print(URL)
```

Comment: Parse URL, edit values of arguments received from input, then rebuild URL. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: @Firelord..Thanks! How would it work if user enters 1 search term or many search terms ?

Comment: Either take one input query at a time, or ask the user to delimit their multiple queries. Then split and add it into arguments of URL. You may have to discard part of input as well and take what you think ought to be relevant. Since you are dealing with Countries' names you can also match input against a list of known valid values (list of them) and discard invalid values. // If user does not provide requisite number of terms then either ask again, or fail, or use some default value.

Comment: Sorry could you please code ? I am kind of lost . Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope. Figure this out. That's the fun part on [SO]. You need guidance not the full-fledged code. That's why I gave you links to the docs. That's all from me. :)

Comment: not a problem. Thanks for link!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you take multiple inputs.

```
a = input("Enter terms A:")
b = input("Enter terms B:")

URL="https://covid.org/data?terms={}&terms={}&start=2021-01-01T00:00:00Z&end=2021-01-31T00:00:00Z".format(a,b)
print(URL)
```

the result is

```
Enter terms A:test
Enter terms B:tester
https://covid.org/data?terms=test&terms=tester&start=2021-01-01T00:00:00Z&end=2021-01-31T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: The reason is because I am not sure how any inputs will be entered by User ? It can be 1 or 2 or more than 2..